# How to correct this simple Laravel DB query to put the where condition string parameter into the '' character?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am pretty new in Laravel and I have the following problem.

Performing this simple update query:

```
$affected = DB::update('update pm_user set checked = 1 where email = ?', ['email' => $email]);
```

this generates this SQL query:

```
update pm_user set checked = 1 where email = my.email@gmail.com
```

that goes into error because the SQL query to perform have to be:

```
update pm_user set checked = 1 where email = 'my.email@gmail.com'
```

The **email** field is a **string** so have to be placed into **''**

How can I modify my original PHP query to put the content of **$email** variable into the **''**?

Comment: If you want do it directly in update query, you can just put quotes there: 

`$affected = DB::update('update pm_user set checked = 1 where email = "?" ', ['email' => $email]);`

But it's better to follow @alexey-mezenin suggestion and do it with QueryBuilder or Eloquent model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Eloquent:

```
PmUser::where('email', $email)->update(['checked' => 1]);
```

Or Query Builder:

```
DB::table('pm_user')->where('email', $email)->update(['checked' => 1]);
```